# Selecting checkbox to select all underlying chechbox JavaScript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="test1" />Check all A
<p id="test1">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="testA1" />A
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testA2" />A
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testA3" />A
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testA4" />A
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testA5" />A
    <br />
</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="test2" />Check all B
<p id="test2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testB1" />B
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testB2" />B
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testB3" />B
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testB4" />B
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testB5" />B
    <br />
</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="test3" />Check all C
<p id="test3">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testC1" />C
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testC2" />C
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testC3" />C
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testC4" />C
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testC5" />C
    <br />
</p>
```

I have 3 checkboxes with underlying 5 each checkboxes. If i check check All A, all underlying checkboxes should be selected.
Same thing should happened as the other Check all B and Check all C are selected. If i have to undo either of the  Check all A,B and C, its
underlying boxes should be uncheck.How would i do it in html? It seems to be needing a javascript but i don't know where to start.And one thing, if i undo the check all
, all underlying checkboxes should not be unchecked. 
Hope anyone can help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I renamed the checkAll and gave them a class

Plain JS since you did not tag jQuery - scroll down for jQuery version

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var chkAll = document.querySelectorAll(".chkAll");
  for (var i = 0; i < chkAll.length; i++) {
    chkAll[i].onclick = function() {
      var id = this.id, chk = this.checked;
      var subChk = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=" + id + "]"); // starts with id
      for (var i = 0; i < subChk.length; i++) {
        subChk[i].checked = chk;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="testA" class="chkAll" />Check all A
<p id="test1">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="testA1" />A
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testA2" />A
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testA3" />A
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testA4" />A
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testA5" />A
  <br />
</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="testB" class="chkAll" />Check all B
<p id="test2">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testB1" />B
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testB2" />B
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testB3" />B
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testB4" />B
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testB5" />B
  <br />
</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="testC" class="chkAll" />Check all C
<p id="test3">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testC1" />C
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testC2" />C
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testC3" />C
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testC4" />C
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testC5" />C
  <br />
</p>
```

jQuery - including toggling parent checkbox if any unchecked or all checked

```js
$(function() {
  $(".chkAll").on("click", function() {
    var id = this.id, chk = this.checked;
    $("[id^=" + id + "]").prop("checked", chk);
  });
  $(".checkBoxClass").on("click", function() {
    var chk = $(this).parent().find(".checkBoxClass").length == $(this).parent().find(".checkBoxClass:checked").length;
    $(this).parent().prev().prop("checked", chk);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="testA" class="chkAll" />Check all A
<p id="test1">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="testA1" />A
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testA2" />A
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testA3" />A
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testA4" />A
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testA5" />A
  <br />
</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="testB" class="chkAll" />Check all B
<p id="test2">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testB1" />B
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testB2" />B
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testB3" />B
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testB4" />B
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testB5" />B
  <br />
</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="testC" class="chkAll" />Check all C
<p id="test3">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testC1" />C
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testC2" />C
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testC3" />C
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testC4" />C
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testC5" />C
  <br />
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```js
$(".full").on('change', function(e) {
  var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
  console.log(checked);
  $(this).next('p').find('input').each(function(i, e) {
    if (checked) {
      $(this).prop('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
      $(this).prop('checked', '');
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="full" id="test1" />Check all A
<p id="test1">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="testA1" />A
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testA2" />A
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testA3" />A
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testA4" />A
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testA5" />A
  <br />
</p>
<input type="checkbox" class="full" id="test2" />Check all B
<p id="test2">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testB1" />B
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testB2" />B
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testB3" />B
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testB4" />B
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testB5" />B
  <br />
</p>
<input type="checkbox" class="full" id="test3" />Check all C
<p id="test3">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testC1" />C
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testC2" />C
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testC3" />C
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testC4" />C
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testC5" />C
  <br />
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, we can use jQuery,

```js
$("#test1").change(function(){  //"select all" change
    var status = this.checked; // "select all" checked status
    $('#test1 .checkBoxClass').each(function(){ //iterate all listed checkbox items
        this.checked = status; //change ".checkbox" checked status
    });
});

$("#test2").change(function(){  //"select all" change
    var status = this.checked; // "select all" checked status
    $('#test2 .checkBoxClass').each(function(){ //iterate all listed checkbox items
        this.checked = status; //change ".checkbox" checked status
    });
});

$("#test3").change(function(){  //"select all" change
    var status = this.checked; // "select all" checked status
    $('#test3 .checkBoxClass').each(function(){ //iterate all listed checkbox items
        this.checked = status; //change ".checkbox" checked status
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="test1" />Check all A
<p id="test1">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="testA1" />A
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testA2" />A
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testA3" />A
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testA4" />A
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testA5" />A
    <br />
</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="test2" />Check all B
<p id="test2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testB1" />B
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testB2" />B
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testB3" />B
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testB4" />B
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testB5" />B
    <br />
</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="test3" />Check all C
<p id="test3">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testC1" />C
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testC2" />C
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testC3" />C
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testC4" />C
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="test" id="testC5" />C
    <br />
</p>
```